# What is SINATRA_ENV?

Tags: sinatra

Am I correct that within Sinatra there is no use or mention of SINATRA_ENV? For some reason I thought there was. Here's what I think is true now:

Sinatra bases its sense of environment on RACK_ENV. If RACK_ENV is not defined it defaults to development.

If you use ActiveRecord you will also need to set RAILS_ENV because Rails modules don't pay attention to RACK_ENV and certainly not to SINATRA_ENV

Can someone corroborate this analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You are mostly correct. Some developers will build a `SINATRA_ENV` into their applications (and set `RACK_ENV` to it), but it is not built into the library. Sinatra 2.0 is introducing `APP_ENV`, which will be preferred over `RACK_ENV`.

ActiveRecord appears to check `RACK_ENV` if `RAILS_ENV` is not set, so you shouldn't need to set `RAILS_ENV` manually. This could potentially be a problem with Sinatra 2.0, so that's something to keep in mind. A simple workaround would be to set `RACK_ENV` to `APP_ENV` for backwards compatibility with other gems, or vice-versa.

Within Sinatra applications, classic and modular, you should be using `environment` (or `self.environment` in helpers and routes) and convenience methods such as `development?`, `production?`, etc. instead of inspecting the environment variables explicitly. I've taken to using `Sinatra::Base.environment` (and the aforementioned convenience methods) outside of my application(s) once Sinatra is loaded. For example:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'sinatra', require: 'sinatra/base' # in default group

group :development do
  # ..
end

group :production do
  # ..
end
```

And:

```
# config.ru

require 'bundler/setup'

Bundler.require :default # this loads Sinatra, which inspects e.g. RACK_ENV
Bundler.require Sinatra::Base.environment
```

It bears keeping in mind that Sinatra is a tiny, tiny library (last time I checked, about 2K LOC), and it really does leave a lot of these application concerns in the hands of the developer. There aren't many hard and fast rules!